# Dynamic variable creation language

Tags: variables, dynamic, language-agnostic, programming-languages

Which computer languages will allow code that dynamically extracts a variable name from a string, like user types in an argument "hhh", and the code then knows to reference a variable with the identifier: hhh? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Lots of programming languages have ways of looking up a variable given a string that contains its name... You want a list?

Comment: Lots of them... Generally anything that has an `eval`-type construct can do it, and many languages have many more direct ways. This is not a construction question.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a list of all things.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128561/163768)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/10273534/181772

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The associative array is probably a better idea to use, but just in case, php supports this without putting the code inside an eval function:

```
 <?php

 class ff {

 var $u = "aagg";
 }

 $y = new ff();
 $i = "u";
 echo $y->$i;

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not *exactly* "dynamic variable creation", but you can get pretty much the same effect by using an associative array (a.k.a. dictionary or map). For example, in Python:

```
vars = {}
vars['x'] = 'hello'
vars['y'] = 10
```

With the above code, the keys `'x'` and `'y'` in the dictionary are like dynamic variables for all practical purposes, for example:

```
print vars['x']
> hello

vars['y'] + 6
> 16
```

As a matter of fact, under the hood many programming languages (Python, JavaScript, etc.) use a dictionary of bindings for implementing variables and scoping rules.